# Show that $ \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}} + \frac{z^2}{\sqrt{z^2+x^2}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y+z) $

Tags: inequality, summation, geometric-inequalities, sum-of-squares-method, rearrangement-inequality

Show that for positive reals $x,y,z$ the following inequality holds and that the constant cannot be improved

$$
\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}} + \frac{z^2}{\sqrt{z^2+x^2}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y+z)
$$

**Background**: I was digging through some old correspondence and found a letter from a very young me to Professor Love at the University of Melbourne. I had apparently ask via a letter (yes it was back when we wrote letters) how one could prove the above inequality (my version had $1/\sqrt{3}$ in it). He kindly wrote back but without a full proof. I just found the correspondence today and thought that this was a good question for this site.

Based on his letter and my old writings you can transform the above inequality as follows. First note that
$$
\text{g.l.b.}f(x,y,z) = \text{g.l.b.}f(x,z,y) = k \quad (say)
$$
where g.l.b is the greatest lower bound and $f(x,y,z)$ is the function
$$
\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}} + \frac{z^2}{\sqrt{z^2+x^2}}\right)\bigg/(x+y+z).
$$
and so
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{z^2+x^2\phantom{y}} \geq 2k (x+y+z)
$$
Thus we need to prove that for positive reals $x,y$ and $x$ the following is true and tight:
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{z^2+x^2\phantom{y}} \geq \sqrt{2} (x+y+z)
$$
One approach to prove this (used by Prof. Love) was to apply Hölder's inequality but this unfortunately only gives:
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{z^2+x^2\phantom{y}} \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} (x+y+z)
$$
**Geometric View**: From a geometric view point this inequality can be viewed as stating that the perimeter of $\Delta PQR$ is not less than $\sqrt{2}$ times the sum of the the three edge-lengths of the box of sides $x,y,$ and $z$ and the points $P,Q$ and $R$ are three corners of the box that are not adjacent to each other.

I suspect that this is a "well known" inequality in the right circles but it is still not known to me. Thought that is was a nice problem for lovers of inequalities.

Comment: When $x=y=z$, the inequality is an equality.  No improvement possible.

Comment: @herbsteinberg The $==$ unfortunately does not prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is the best constant. However combining this single case and the partial result proved by Hölder's inequality shows that $2/\sqrt{3} \leq k \leq \sqrt{2}$. I am assuming that is this what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x=y=z$ the inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\geq k(x+y+z)$ gives $k\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

The Peter Scholze's solution for $k=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$:

By Rearrangement $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\right)}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)}\geq\frac{x+y+z}{\sqrt2},$$ where the last inequality it's just $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)^4}{x^2+y^2}\geq0.$$
In the making of Rearrangement we used the following reasoning.

The triples $\left(\frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{x^2z^2}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}},\frac{y^2z^2}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\right)$ have the opposite ordering, which gives a possibility to use Rearrangement.

Comment: Very nice! I think that some more explanation on how one goes from the equality to inequality (i.e. changing $\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$ to $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ )would be very beneficial to many given that the only condition on $x,y$ and $z$ is that they be positive reals. Thanks for the solution

Comment: @vand  I added something. See now.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2x^2y^2}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)}}\right)}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2(xy+xz+yz)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2+y^2+y^2+z^2}{2}}}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{(xy+xz+yz)^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{(xy+xz+yz)^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{3x^2-y^2}{4}\right)+\frac{(xy+xz+yz)^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{2}-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x^2-y^2)^2}{4(x^2+y^2)}\geq xy+xz+yz-\frac{(xy+xz+yz)^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2(xy+xz+yz)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)^2(x^2+y^2-xz-yz)^2}{x^2+y^2}\geq0.$$

Comment: Could you explain how you use CS and AM-Gm-inequalities here
to get the inequality


$$ \sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2x^2y^2}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)}}\right)}\geq
\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2(xy+xz+yz)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2+y^2+y^2+z^2}{2}}} $$


The left summands under the square root not change so what we want to show is 



$$  \sum_{cyc} \frac{2x^2y^2}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)}} \geq 
 \sum_{cyc} \frac{2(xy+xz+yz)^2}{\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+y^2+y^2+z^2}{2}} $$

and from this point I dont know how you argued.

Comment: For example 
it seems that you next applied AM-GM 
$\sum_i^n x_i \geq \sqrt[n]{x_1 \cdot ... \cdot x_n}$ for
$n=2$ and $x_1= x^2+y^2, x_2= y^2+z^2$ (and their cyclic 
perputations) to get

$$  \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)}} \geq \frac{1}{\frac{x^2+y^2+y^2+z^2}{2}}$$

But from where you obtain the second sum $\sum_{cyc}$ in the demoninator in the right term and what are your 
vectors $v,w$ when you apply the CS $ \langle v,v \rangle \cdot \langle w,w \rangle 
\geq \langle v,w \rangle^2$?

Comment: @user7391733  Now, by C-S $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2y^2}{\frac{x^2+y^2+y^2+z^2}{2}}\geq\frac{(xy+xz+yz)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2+y^2+y^2+z^2}{2}}=\frac{(xy+xz+yz)^2}{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)}.$

Comment: I see. So you take as $v$ the vector
$(\frac{xy}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+y^2+z^2}{2}}}, 
\frac{zx}{\sqrt{\frac{z^2+x^2+x^2+y^2}{2}}}, 
\frac{yz}{\sqrt{\frac{y^2+z^2+z^2+x^2}{2}}})$ and
$w=(\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+y^2+z^2}{2}},
\sqrt{\frac{z^2+x^2+x^2+y^2}{2}},
\sqrt{\frac{y^2+z^2+z^2+x^2}{2}})$ , right? Thank you!

Comment: @user7391733  Yes, of course!

Answer (score 0):

When $x=y=z$, lhs=$\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{x+y+z}{\sqrt{2}}$=rhs, which means that $\sqrt{2}$ is best constant.